# php framework for part of website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a little experience with web development. I have used Codeigniter in the past. I realize that using a framework allows a structured project, but this is usually aimed at the entire site. I have a situation where I have been asked to help out on a site that does not use a framework. The site is basically entirely static. I have been asked to develop a form for registration, which will also include sql interaction. I would love to use codeigniter for my form application but do not know how to add it to the existing site.

Comment: Just registration? What users will be able to do after registration?

Comment: Yeah just registration. Basically it is registration for an event. They fill in their info, then they are transferred to PayPal for payment. Then I will have PayPal handling etc. Once done, that's it, they are registered for the event. No user account or anything.

Comment: Can you recreate a sub-domain for the event registration? That would likely be the least disruptive to the existing site.

Comment: Never thought of that. A site within a site, ish.. never tried this either. Is it fairly easy? This is a godaddy site, I should mention.

Comment: you don't even need a subdoman will answer in a second

Comment: Ok thats how to do it. However *the first thing* you need to do is step through the tutorial in the codeigniter manual. Do that tutorial and then you will know how to make a contact form and save it to a database. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: GoDaddy does support subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder called 'contact' in your public html folder. 
Put the main index.php of codeigniter in that folder

If you are able to - above the server root public html folder - put the codeigniter system folder and the application folder.
Protip - rename the folders for the version and/or what they are and do - so like if you download version 3.07 of codeigniter label them:
system307 
appcontact

Ok back to your contact folder and the index.php file - look to where the application and system folder paths are - change these to like

```
$system_path = '../../system307';
$application_folder = '../../appcontact';
```

In the contact folder make your htaccess file it will probably be something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /contact/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Remember to do your configs etc in the application folder. 
Make your contact form controller the default controller. 
And thats it. Now if you link to 'contact' in your nav bar it will pull up the form automagically.

Comment: Awesome info. I will try this out. If it works, which it seems legit, I will mark as answer.

Comment: Ahem I already know it works :-) But if you have any issues just make a new post. And even if you have used codeigniter before - go through the tutorial first to brush up on everything.

Comment: This is a good answer and will work perfectly. But I cannot resist pointing out that it's essentially the same thing as creating a subdomain but without the benefit of being known by domain name servers. With a subdomain you should also be able to use the "standard" .htaccess redirect without referencing the contact folder. (Admittedly, not a big deal.)

Comment: when you say "above the server root public html folder", is this critical? I don't believe that I can get past the root directory.

Comment: if its just a contact form its not a big deal. so in the default codeigniter application view folder/welcome_message.php file at the very top you will see <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?> Put that at the top of your view files. You will see something similar in the Welcome controller <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); Put that at the top of your controllers and models.

Comment: @dFriend - the htaccess file is to allow you to remove 'index.php' from the url. its for codeigniter. otherwise - not sure i agree in this specific case but now you have me curious about subdomains so thanks.

Comment: and when you move on to your next website - use a host that allows you access above server root its not that unusual even in shared hosting.